# Scaled QPixmap looks bad

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qpixmap

I have the following widget:

```
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(r'pics\cdaudio.png').scaled(100, 100)
```

The image is scaled down, from 256x256. It looks pretty choppy:

[image]

How can I scale it smoothly from within Qt?

Comment: Did you take a look at the docs by any chance?

Comment: Didn't know that scaled gets parameters beside the resolution. Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `transformMode` parameter:

```
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(r'pics\cdaudio.png').scaled(100, 100, transformMode=QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
```

Answer (score 5):

According to @iTayb, here's what I came up with:

```cpp
// Scale the source to the requested size with 
//  the KeepAspectRatio as aspectMode & SmoothTransformation as mode
*source = source->scaled(width, height, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
target->setPixmap(*source);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the SVG format (and the Qt SVG module for this) if possible ?

Comment: Who said that my source is a SVG?